# finding the continuous function $x $ on [-1, 1]

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

find the continuous function $x $ on $[-1, 1]$ such that 
\begin{equation} 
\frac{|\int_{-1}^{0} x   \mathrm{d}t-\int_{0}^{1}x \mathrm{d}t|}{max_{[-1, 1]}|x|}\geq 2
\end{equation}

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I am trying with many continuous functions but not getting

Comment: Are you sure such a function exists?

Comment: "I am trying with many continuous functions but not getting" Then show the ones you tried. In fact, *show anything at all* apart from the statement of the problem you were given.

Comment: the question appears in functional analysis by the author Kreyszig

Comment: "the question appears in functional analysis by the author Kreyszig" Is this last comment supposed to describe some **personal** try?

Comment: Is  $x$ a function or a variable here? If a function, then (a) what is it a function of, and what takes values in $[-1,1]$? and (b) consider the discontinuous sign function

Answer (score 1):

Such a continuous function does not exist!

If $M:=\max_{[-1, 1]}|x|>0$ and the equality holds then $x$ has to be constant in $(0,1]$, and $[-1,0)$, with different constants (because otherwise $\left|\int_{-1}^{0} x  dt-\int_{0}^{1}x dt\right|=0$).

Hence $x$ can not be continuous in $[-1,1]$.

In fact, since $x$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and in $[-1,0]$, if $x$ is not constant on $(0,1]$ and $[-1,0)$, then at least one of the integrals $\int_{-1}^{0} |x|  dt$ and $\int_{0}^{1}|x| dt$ is strictly less than $M$ and
$$2M=\left|\int_{-1}^{0} x  dt-\int_{0}^{1}x dt\right|\leq \int_{-1}^{0} |x|  dt+\int_{0}^{1}|x| dt< 2M.$$
Contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:

You may assume $\max_{-1\leq t\leq1}x(t)=1$. You now want
$$2=\left|\int_{-1}^0 x(t)\>dt+\int_0^1 -x(t)\>dt\right|\leq\int_{-1}^0\bigl|x(t)\bigr|\>dt+\int_0^1\bigl|x(t)\bigr|\>dt\leq2\ .$$
This can only be realized if we have $=$ instead of $\leq\,$, hence $x(t)$ should be $\geq0$ when $t\leq0$ and $\leq0$ when $t\geq0$, and more.